# angular ngFor loop with True false condition

Tags: angular, typescript

i m trying to solve this condition if condition =true button show otherwise button hidden

OfferMatching() {
this.getmatchoffer.filter(obj => {
debugger
for (let i = 0; i < this.applicationJobList.length; i++){
var Options = { hour12: false };
const offerStartDate = new Date(this.applicationJobList[i].offerSteps.initial.jobDateoffer).toLocaleDateString();
const offerStartTime= new Date(this.applicationJobList[i].offerSteps.initial.startTime).toLocaleTimeString('it-IT',Options);
const offerEndTime = new Date(this.applicationJobList[i].offerSteps.initial.endTime).toLocaleTimeString('it-IT',Options);
const bookDateoffer = new Date (obj.offerSteps.initial.jobDateoffer).toLocaleDateString() ;
const bookstartTime = new Date(obj.offerSteps.initial.startTime).toLocaleTimeString('it-IT',Options);
const bookendTime = new Date(obj.offerSteps.initial.endTime).toLocaleTimeString('it-IT',Options);
debugger
if (bookDateoffer === offerStartDate ) {

```
      if (bookstartTime  < offerStartTime) {

        if (bookendTime < offerEndTime) {
       this.samemOffer = false;

       } else {
       this.samemOffer = true;
       }

      } else if (bookstartTime > offerEndTime) {

        if (bookendTime > offerEndTime) {
         this.samemOffer = false;

       } else {
        this.samemOffer = true;
      }

       } else {
       this.samemOffer = true;
        }
    }
  }

})
```

}
this is angular ts file code

{{i+1}}
                                  
                            
                                
                                
                                  {{c}}

```
                        </div>
```

please resolve my issue

this code in angular HTML

Comment: Can you please format your text? Make it as code with ``

Comment: first line its my angular ts file code

Comment: Jaba is right, your code is very hard to read like this and could use some formatting. I also don't understand your question in the first sentence very well, so could you maybe clarify? All this is not to demotivate you, but to motivate other's to answer your question. Welcome on the forum by the way .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming you have an array of objects that you want to iterate over.

***First Approach***

Filter out from the array and only keep the items you want to show. You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method for this

***Second approach***
Create a custom pipe and handle the logic there the return true and false to the *ngIf so your code should be like this

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'resolve',
  pure:true
})
export class ResolvePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(bookstartTime: any, offerStartTime: any, bookendTime: any, offerEndTime: any): boolean {
    if (bookstartTime < offerStartTime) {
      return bookendTime > offerEndTime
    } else if (bookstartTime > offerEndTime) {
      return bookendTime < offerEndTime
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
// In the HTML
<div 
*ngIf="resolve | 
data.bookstartTime:data.offerStartTime:data.bookendTime:data.offerEndTime">
hello
</div>
```

**[NOTE] Don't forget to add your own typing and also don't forget to add this pipe into your ng module declarations array if you want to go with the 2nd approach**